# best practices passing path params to RQ useMutation hook

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I created a hook that will use a react-query `useMutation` behind the scenes, the hook will receive an ID to be used in the request like so:

```js
const useMyHook = (id) => {
  return mutationFn: (payload) => {
    axios.post(`https://some-url/${id}`, payload)
  }
}
```

usually, I will pass the ID directly in the execution of `useMyHook` The thing is, the ID should be retrieved with an asynchronous process, so should I pass the ID in the `mutate` payload or should I handle the ID in a `React.state` and pass the value to `useMyHook`?

### Using React.state

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [id, setId] = React.state(null);
  const { mutate } = useMyHook(id);

  getId().then(newId => {
    setId(newId)
    mutate(payload);
  });
}
```

### Using the payload

```js
// please note I change the hook implementation for using the payload in path parms
const useMyHook = () => {
  return mutationFn: (payload) => {
    axios.post(`https://some-url/${payload.id}`, payload)
  }
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  const { mutate } = useMyHook();

  someAsyncronousProcess().then(id => mutate({ ...payload, id }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a preference question. If you need the id for something else as well, you'd probably want to put it in react state, or write a `useQuery` for it.

Comment: Thanks for answering... suppose I don't need the ID for anything else... You would be sending information to the BE that is not needed, so why send it at all? the real question would be, RQ offer a different approach for handling this scenario? may be allowing mutate to accept more than one parameter?

Comment: it can't accept more than one param because we use options for callback as the second param: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/mastering-mutations-in-react-query#mutations-only-take-one-argument-for-variables